# How can I restore `cmd.exe` executable?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

I locked myself out of my old windows 7 machine (forgot my admin password). However, I know about [this sethc.exe trick](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/reset-password-windows-7.htm) to reset a forgotten password. So, I created a bootable linux distro, swapped `sethc.exe` and `cmd.exe` executables, booted windows, set a new admin password, booted linux and swapped the executables back. Unfortunately, I was too bored/not paying attention and ended up actually deleting my `cmd.exe` executable.

Even though powershell works just fine, not having a `cmd.exe` might lead to unexpected things. It would be nice to somehow restore that, but I am not a windows admin/haven't used windows for quite a while. Any ideas how one could restore this executable?

Comment: `sfc /scannow`? [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)

Comment: Thank you, @DavidPostill, it restored the executable back into place. Magically.

Comment: Yes, the "System File Checker" utility, that's made specifically to restore missing/corrupted system files, is "magic". ;) j/k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How can I restore `cmd.exe` executable?

Use `sfc /scannow`

> System File Checker is a utility in Windows that allows users to scan for corruptions in Windows system files and restore corrupted files. This article describes how to run the System File Checker tool (SFC.exe) to scan your system files and to repair missing or corrupted system files. If a Windows Resource Protection (WRP) file is missing or is corrupted, Windows may not behave as expected. For example, some Windows functions may not work, or Windows may crash.

---

#### How do I run the System File Checker tool (SFC.exe)?

> To do this, follow these steps:
>
> **Open an elevated command prompt**
>
> - Windows 8.1 or Windows 8
>
>   Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search. Or, if you are using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the
>     screen, and then click Search. Type Command Prompt in the Search box,
>     right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator. If
>     you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation,
>     type the password, or click Allow.
>
>   [image: A screenshot for this step.]
> - Windows 10, Windows 7, or Windows Vista
>
>   Click Start, type Command Prompt or cmd in the Search box, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator.
>     If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a
>     confirmation, type the password, or click Allow.
>
>   [image: A screenshot for this step.]
>
> **At the command prompt**
>
> Type the following command, and then press ENTER:
>
> ```
>     `sfc /scannow`
> ```
>
> [image: A screenshot for this step.]
>
> The sfc /scannow command will scan all protected system files, and
>   replace corrupted files with a cached copy that is located in a
>   compressed folder at %WinDir%\System32\dllcache.    The %WinDir%
>   placeholder represents the Windows operating system folder. For
>   example, C:\Windows.
>
> Note: Do not close this Command Prompt window until the verification
>   is 100% complete. The scan results will be shown after this process is
>   finished.
>
> **After the process is finished**
>
> You may receive one of the following messages:
>
> - Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
>
>   This means that you do not have any missing or corrupted system
>     files.
> - Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.
>
>   To resolve this problem, perform the System File Checker scan in
>     safe mode, and make sure that the PendingDeletes and PendingRenames
>     folders exist under %WinDir%\WinSxS\Temp.
> - Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. Details are included in the CBS.Log
>     %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.
>
>   To view the detail information about the system file scan and
>     restoration, go to How to view details of the System File Checker
>     process.
> - Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log
>     %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.
>
>   To repair the corrupted files manually, view details of the System
>     File Checker process to find the corrupted file, and then manually
>     replace the corrupted file with a known good copy of the file.

Source [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)

Comment: bro I have problem with cmd.exe itself, how can i run these commands??

Comment: @ArbazAlam Use an alternative shell, for example PowerShell.

Comment: often does not work. it does not work for me even if i use dism too.